# Migrating From Digital Ocean to Heroku

Tags: heroku, mariadb, database-migration, digital-ocean

I have an app that uses Flash, MariaDB, and Python which I currently host on Digital Ocean. I am planning to move to Heroku for scalability purposes, but I am unable to find any resources online talking about the process of migrating data from Digital Ocean to Heroku. Can anyone explain the process? Thanks

Comment: Heroku comes with a lot of limitations (ephemeral file system, daily restarts, no ssh). If I were you I would just move to another VPS provider. Heroku is more suited if you want your users to deploy their own instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku provides Dynos (application runtime) and Add-Ons (databases and other tools).

First create a Dyno (it can also be free) and deploy your Python application (you can push the code from [Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) or create a Docker image for the [Heroku Docker Registry](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deployment)).
Then enable the [MariaDB add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/jawsdb-maria) to setup your storage (there is a free plan here too, check if this is suitable in your case).

You need to provide the MariaDB connection string as environment variable, this is explained [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jawsdb-maria#using-jawsdb-maria-with-python-django)

Finally it is a good idea to use [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) for all environment variables that your application might need (ie tokens, secrets).

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66858780/9409877